# Strcmp Problem Segmantation Fault insert method not working

Tags: c, string, gcc, methods, segmentation-fault

I used GDB, and realised that the problem was reaching these line of codes:

in main:

'''

```
    else if(strcmp("insert",arg[1])==0){
    insert("a.txt","Cem","Mec","Cem","-a");

}
```

'''
insert method:

'''

void insert(char *filename, char *insertedWord, char *searchedWord,char *oldsearchedWord, char *ab){

```
if(strcmp("-a",ab) == 0){

    strcat(searchedWord," ");
    strcat(searchedWord, insertedWord);
    replace(filename,searchedWord,oldsearchedWord); 

}
else if(strcmp("-b",ab) == 0){

    strcat(insertedWord," ");
    strcat(insertedWord, searchedWord);
    replace(filename,insertedWord,oldsearchedWord);

}
```

}
'''

and the error is:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2_unaligned ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:32
32  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.

I checked my replace method. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to `strcat` using a string literal as target. You are not allowed to do this because string literals are usually placed on read only data segments and attempting to modify them is undefined behaviour.

switch to

```
char insertedWord[256] = "cem";
char searchedWord[256] = "mec";
...
```

and then pass those (modfiable) arrays instead.